# How to declare particular line in file (/etc/fstab) with Augeas?

Tags: augeas

I'm trying to use Augeas to declare/ensure that a particular mount point exists in fstab. If it already is there, make sure it has these $settings, otherwise create a new line that does.

But I haven't been able to get augeas to do that. I can get it to modify an existing line and I can get it add a new line. But not *both*, as in (pseudocode):

```
if (line_exists) {
    check_and_modify_line()
} else {
    create_new_line()
}
```

To `check_and_modify_line()`, this works:

```
set /files/etc/fstab/*[file="/mnt/ISO"]/file "/mnt/ISO"
set /files/etc/fstab/*[file="/mnt/ISO"]/spec "nas:/ISO/iso"
set /files/etc/fstab/*[file="/mnt/ISO"]/vfstype "nfs"
set /files/etc/fstab/*[file="/mnt/ISO"]/opt "intr"
set /files/etc/fstab/*[file="/mnt/ISO"]/dump "0"
set /files/etc/fstab/*[file="/mnt/ISO"]/passno "0"
```

To `create_new_line()`, this works:

```
set /files/etc/fstab/01/spec "nas:/ISO/iso"
set /files/etc/fstab/01/file "/mnt/ISO"
set /files/etc/fstab/01/vfstype "nfs"
set /files/etc/fstab/01/opt[1] "intr"
set /files/etc/fstab/01/dump "0"
set /files/etc/fstab/01/passno "0"
```

But the secret sauce that combines the above two sections into a single one eludes me. And I thought that Augeas was supposed to be declarative/idempotent, so it surprises me quite a lot that I can't tell Augeas: "Make sure this line exists".

There also don't seem to be any if/then/else style blocks, because then I could:

```
if match /files/etc/fstab/*[file="/mnt/ISO"]
    defnode isonode /files/etc/fstab/*[file="/mnt/ISO"]
else
    defnode isonode /files/etc/fstab/01

set $isnode/file "/mnt/ISO"
set $isnode/bla "bla-bla"
```

Is there a way to do this all in a single bunch of "set" operations or a single .aug file, so I can run a single:

```
sudo augtool < mountpoint.aug
```

Sure I could use a couple of augeas puppet resources with mutually exclusive `onlyif`-s, or a wrapper e.g. in bash or perl with some combination of grep, sed etc. but then I might as well stick to using that completely and not Augeas...

By the way, is there more comprehensive official documentation for *using* Augeas than the tiny [tour](http://augeas.net/tour.html)? The entire [documentation](http://augeas.net/docs/index.html) seems to be dedicated to new lens *developers*, not for the presumably more numberous lens *users*.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make use of a higher level language (C, ruby, perl, php, etc.) for the conditionals, what you can do is use `defvar` for that purpose:

```
#!/usr/bin/augtool -Asf

# The -A combined with this makes things much faster
# by loading only the required lens/file
transform Fstab.lns incl /etc/fstab
load

# $noentry will match /files/etc/fstab only if the entry isn't there yet
defvar noentry /files/etc/fstab[count(*[file="/mnt/ISO"])=0]

# Create the entry if it's missing
set $noentry/01/spec "nas:/ISO/iso"
set $noentry/01/file "/mnt/ISO"

# Now amend existing entry or finish creating the missing one
defvar entry /files/etc/fstab/*[file="/mnt/ISO"]

set $entry/spec "nas:/ISO/iso"
set $entry/vfstype "nfs"
set $entry/opt "intr"
set $entry/dump "0"
set $entry/passno "0"
```

As a note, I'm currently working on Lua support in Augeas (see https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/pull/300), so it's likely that the *next release* will allow to write something like this (although the syntax might still change):

```lua
#!/usr/bin/augtool -lAsf
--- pass the spec as spec=<spec>
--- pass the file as mount=<mount>

spec = os.getenv("spec")
mount = os.getenv("mount")

transform("Fstab.lns", "/etc/fstab", false)
load()

file_path = "etc/fstab/*[file='" .. mount .. "']"
if (aug_matches(file_path) == 0) then
  defnode("file", "etc/fstab/01", nil)
  set("$file/spec", spec)
  set("$file/file", mount)
else
  defvar("file", file_path)
end

set("$file/spec", spec)
set("$file/vfstype", "nfs")
set("$file/opt", "intr")
set("$file/dump", "0")
set("$file/passno", "0")
```

which can then be called as:

```sh
mount=/mnt/ISO spec=nas:/ISO/iso ./aug.lua
```

Comment: The first example made sense after reading https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/wiki/Path-expressions and trying it out in the interactive `augtool`. However, the variable `noentry` is poorly named. It would be better called `conditional_base`. (is may or may not be (as appropriate) the file to work on (`fstab` it this case).